# Pandas - Number of rows to the last row in a group that meets a requirement

Tags: python, pandas

My data is like this

```
date          group     meet_criteria
2020-03-31      1          no
2020-04-01      1          yes
2020-04-02      1          no
2020-04-03      1          no
2020-04-04      1          yes
2020-04-05      1          no
2020-03-31      2          yes
2020-04-01      2          no
```

I would like to create another column which will equal 1 divide by the number of days since the last date in a group that the column `meet_criteria` is yes (the current `meet_criteria` is excluded and if a group has never met the criteria then the value will be 0.)

My desired data will look like this

```
date          group     meet_criteria      last_time_met_criteria
2020-03-31      1          no                     0
2020-04-01      1          yes                    0
2020-04-02      1          no                     1
2020-04-03      1          no                     0.5
2020-04-04      1          yes                    0.333333
2020-04-05      1          no                     1
2020-03-31      2          yes                    0
2020-04-01      2          no                     1
```

Is there any way to do this efficiently in pandas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) & subsequent calculations in pandas.

Here's a fully worked example with your data (original data loaded into a variable called `df`, and `df.date` converted to `datetime` first)

```
# sorting necessary for how `merge_asof` will be used  
df2 = df.sort_values(['date', 'group'])

# construct the `right` data frame of dates to lookup
df_meet_criteria = df2[df2.meet_criteria == 'yes'].copy()
df_meet_criteria['date_met_criteria'] = df_meet_criteria.date

# merge 
# `by`: columns to do regular merge on
# `on`: columns to do as_of merge on
# `allow_exact_matches`: True -> closed interval, False -> open interval, 
#                        i.e. latest date before current date
last_date = pd.merge_asof(
    df2, 
    df_meet_criteria, 
    by='group', 
    on='date', 
    allow_exact_matches=False,
    suffixes=('', '_y')
).sort_values(['group', 'date'])

# calculate the inverse_days.
last_date['days_since'] = (last_date.date - last_date.date_met_criteria).dt.days    
last_date.loc[last_date.days_since == 0, 'days_since'] = np.nan
last_date['last_time_met_criteria'] = (1 / last_date.days_since).fillna(0)
final = last_date[['date', 'group', 'meet_criteria', 'last_time_met_criteria']]
```

final dataframe looks like this:

```
        date  group meet_criteria  last_time_met_criteria
0 2020-03-31      1            no                0.000000
2 2020-04-01      1           yes                0.000000
4 2020-04-02      1            no                1.000000
5 2020-04-03      1            no                0.500000
6 2020-04-04      1           yes                0.333333
7 2020-04-05      1            no                1.000000
1 2020-03-31      2           yes                0.000000
3 2020-04-01      2            no                1.000000
```